# Add custom data to IdentityUser in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been reading tutorial articles for a few days now, and most of the tutorials show either how to create login with `IdentityUser` class and Facebook, Google etc.(but no additional user data) or how to create user with their details without authentication.

My goal is to create application where a user can:

1. Login with Facebook(done)
2. Add personal data after that
3. Link personal data with the User entry in the default database that is created from ASP.NET

My question is:
Should I write a standalone controller and link it to the created user and how it is done?
Or should I add the additional data to `ApplicationUser` class?

I will be happy if someone share a good resource on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

A standalone class linked to the Application user should be the best solution.

You should create a table with the structure: USERID, DATA1,DATA2....

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Well can you share a resource on how to perform the link between the two models?